# Send image id on-page with json/ajax without reloading

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, twitter-bootstrap

I'm seeking help to make the carousel item active when `$thisImage_id` matches the carousel item's `$carouselImage_id` without reloading the page.

onclicking the image, it should send its `$thisImage_id` to the self page without reloading so that carousel item can be active.

```
<form onsubmit="return false">
    <img width="100" src="<?php if(isset($image_source) && !empty($image_source)){echo $image_source;}?>" />

    <input type="hidden" name="image_id" value="<?php echo $thisImage_id;?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

below is the carousel item div which will receive the sent image id from the above FORM.

```
<div class="item <?php if($carouselImage_id==$thisImage_id){echo 'active';}?>">
```

in above I think I cannot use php if comparison statement, it should be something json work here to echo the 'active' if that image is clicked.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: That server - client round trip is not required (and would not work anyway). The solution is almost certainly some simple javascript - Please just explain what you are trying to achieve, in plain language

Comment: ok. I have fetched many images from database and displayed in a page. When a user click on a image they will see a modal without reloading the page, this modal has a commenting form of ajax which can post comment to mysql without reloading and without closing the modal. On the modal user can go to previous image or next image to submit comment (as like as facebook). Now i'm trying to achieve, when a user click on a image > modal opens> the clicked image should be active in the modal carousel. Is it understandable?

Comment: Sure, well you can do that in javascript. Give the clickable images a data attribute with the id,  then capture that in click event in js and use it to set the relevant image to active: http://jsfiddle.net/vevzpbd9/1/

Comment: plus 1 it helpep, thanks..